# Zend sending email

Tags: php, zend-framework, message-queue, zend-mail

i have a project that need to send email. and i use zend as my framework.

i use XSL for email templat and save email parameter as array that will turn to XML before send the email.

i create my own implementation multithread class utilize CURL for sending email.

any better development approach for queue & sending email ?